# graphicx regression in TL 2018? \convertMPtoPDF undefined in preamble

Tags: graphics, errors, pdftex, metapost, includegraphics

Consider the following MNWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% \input{supp-pdf.mkii}
\newbox\mypic
\sbox\mypic{\includegraphics[height=6.5ex]{moral-compass-lliw10}}
\begin{document}
Hylo byd!
\end{document}
```

This fails to compile with pdfTeX with the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...lx bp\relax \fi \fi \convertMPtoPDF 
                                                  {\Gin@base \Gin@ext }{1}{1...
l.13 ...phics[height=6.5ex]{moral-compass-lliw10}}

?
```

whereas, with some earlier version of TeX Live (probably, but not certainly TL 2017), there was no problem.

`moral-compass-lliw10` is an MPS image, so it must be converted for inclusion when compiling with pdfTeX. If the image is included in the body, there is no problem. However, if the image is used in the preamble, compilation fails.

A workaround is to uncomment the line

```
\input{supp-pdf.mkii}
```

However, this was not necessary before, so the need is apparently a regression.

Is this behaviour expected? That is, ought it never to have worked? If not, is it a bug in `graphicx` or something else? This error is not documented in `graphicx` manual which never, so far as I can tell, suggests that loading `supp-pdf.mkii` manually is necessary.

I'm using TeX Live 2018 (updated this week because I mistakenly thought it might be a bug and it might have been fixed).

Comment: the mp support file is loaded at begin document (been that way for a long while, I think)

Comment: `\AtBeginDocument{\sbox\mypic{...}}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Not that long? This did work. I was compiling the same code ....

Comment: @egreg Is there a way of testing if I'm in the preamble? So that my macro would work whether it is in the preamble or in the body? (I'm not really using `\sbox{}` - at least, not directly.)

Comment: Look at the contents of `\everypar`.

Comment: @cfr it was already `\AtBeginDocument` when "we" took control of pdftex.def into the graphics-def distribution in 2016 https://github.com/latex3/graphics-def/commit/53b8f5e32ea5d8a3946231acc1b5dc2fabdb0617#diff-e08b8032b5d66c1ff0aab02670794126R1852

Comment: @cfr in general typesetting anything before begin document is not really supported, nothing is set up in the preamble.

Comment: @cfr you could test with `\ifx\@begindocumenthook\@undefined`.

Comment: can you not use `\AtBeginDocument{\sbox\mypic{\includegraphics[height=6.5ex]{moral-compass-lliw10}}}`

Comment: @cfr even better should be `\ifx\@nodocument\relax`.

Comment: @cfr and even better might be to redefine your macro `\AtBeginDocument`.

Answer (score 6):

The MPS support file is loaded `\AtBeginDocument` so you need to typeset after that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newbox\mypic
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \sbox\mypic{\includegraphics[height=6.5ex]{moral-compass-lliw10}}
\begin{document}
Hylo byd!
\end{document}
```

It has been that way for a long time, although texlive 2016 is the oldest version I have to hand to test.

In general it is not supported to do *any* typesetting before `\begin{document}` it sometimes seems to work to set text in a box so avoiding the `Missing \begin{document}` error, but latex is in a very unstable state if typesetting in those conditions, fonts, math mode and other things are not set up and finalised until `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Confirmed for TL 2012 onwards.